# Not all logs are in AWS Elasticsearch Service using Serilog during peak load

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, .net-core, serilog

Tech stack:
AWS ECS (.net core) + Serilog + Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch + AWS Elasticsearch

I noticed that sometimes I can't find some logs in the ES.

I made some test to reproduce such a problem and these are the results:

```
| Raised log entries (in parallel)  | Found log enries in ES    | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 100000                            | 100000                    |
| 500000                            | 172244                    |
| 500000                            | 163841                    |
| 500000                            | 174947                    |
| 500000                            | 155788                    |
```

So as you can see it's quite reproducible.

I turned on https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics for Serilog but it doesn't say anything. CloudWatch also says that everything is fine.

Original configuration of Serilog:

```
builder.UseSerilog(
    (hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .Enrich.WithServiceName(serviceName)
        .WriteTo.Console(new JsonFormatter(renderMessage: true))
        .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(hostingContext.Configuration["elasticsearch"] ?? "http://localhost:9200"))
        {
            AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
            IndexDecider = (ev, offset) => string.Format("{0}.{1}", index, System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd")),
        })
        .Destructure.UsingAttributes()
        );
```

Maybe someone already had such problems so I would really appreciate if you share your experience

**UPDATE**

I've found next logs from AppInsights

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: at
>   System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper+d__2.MoveNext
>   (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a) at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result (System.Private.CoreLib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<CreateConnectionAsync>d__40.MoveNext
>   (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a) at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result (System.Private.CoreLib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+d__45.MoveNext
>   (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a) at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result (System.Private.CoreLib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<SendWithRetryAsync>d__37.MoveNext
>   (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a) at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at
>   System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler+d__4.MoveNext
>   (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a) at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at
>   System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler+d__2.MoveNext
>   (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a) Inner exception
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException handled at
>   System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper+d__2.MoveNext: at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at
>   System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper+d__2.MoveNext
>   (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)

during *http://elasticsearch:9200/_bulk* operation

Comment: Using `Serilog.Sinks.Async` in "drop events" mode ?

Comment: @RubenBartelink updated a question with configuration

Comment: from here https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-async I see that ES sink already performs asynchronous batching natively and do not benefit from this wrapper.

Comment: Good point - I wonder does it define buffering (inc dropping rather than unbonded growth) rules ? (I've not used/looked at it so will step away!)